# app crashes after button click once password is entered

Tags: android, passwords, crash

I have created an app whereby the user enters a password, clicks the button and it takes them to a new activity. i have made a create password activity where the user first  enters a new password and this then takes them to the main activity. in the main activity, the user would type the created password, click the button and it would take them to the next activity. however upon clicking the button after password entry (correct or incorrect) the app crashes. can anyone advise please?
Android Manifest below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.junaidandroid.androidsecure">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.junaidandroid.CreatePassword">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.junaidandroid.androidsecure.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.junaidandroid.Activity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.junaidandroid.NoteLauncher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Java Code for MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
Button button2;

String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);


    //load the password
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
    password = settings.getString("password", "");

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = editText.getText().toString();

            if (text.equals(password)){
                //enter the app
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

I HAVE NOW ADDED THE LOGCAT ERROR BELOW:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.junaidandroid.androidsecure, PID: 2569
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.junaidandroid.androidsecure.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Show your error logcat

Comment: i am new to android studio, how do i find the logcat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Which line does it fail on? Also, please post the layout file.

Comment: error logcat has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have write correct findviewbyid of edittext. This null pointer exception is occur just because 
Of you trying to getting value from edittext which id is not correct.This edit text id should be same as in xml file you have declared.

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id);
```

Comment: yes, I have managed to resolve the issue, it was exactly how you just pointed out, the ID did not match the one from the XML file hence  why it kept crashing

Comment: There is one thing i would like to suggest you when you without entering the password and click the button your app will be crashed so  change your if condition like this...  if ( !TextUtils.isempty(text) && text.equals(password)){

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark as you haven't posted your logcat...

`editText` should be declared `final` if you want to access it within an inner class. The Exception is being thrown when you try to access it here:

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I am new to android studio and not sure how to get the logcat

Comment: On the bottom bar in Android Studio, select "Android Monitor". Edit your question to include the big block of red text that appears when your app crashes

Comment: the logcat is blank even after the app crashes

Comment: also how would i declare final?

Comment: i have managed to get the logcat can you look at it for me please, much appreciated